# Wordpress/php challenge

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, meta-tags

Currently I have custom wordpress meta fields for a tv show blog that outputs "title" "number" "season" "plot" for each episode. Each episode is a table created that outputs the meta fields together...it is not a post nor page. What i'm trying to accomplish here is put the results in a tabbed slideshow that would look likre this http://beta.abc.go.com/shows/castle/episode-guide?category=Season+3 .  The problems i ran into is that the seasons duplicate for example season 4 would output to be like 4,4,4,4 i was tring to merge them. and have only episodes from a particular season show up on that tab.

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
 <h2><?php echo $item['title'] ?></h2>
 <p> Season <?php echo $item['season'] ?> | Episode <?php echo $item['number'] ?> | Aired <?php echo $item['airdate'] ?></p>
 <p><?php echo $item['plot'] ?></p>"
}
```

That is currently how the results are being outputted

Comment: I fail to see how this code could output 4,4,4,4...

Comment: Sorry, the reason it outputs 4,4,4,4 is because when it's inside the slideshow it is inside a <li> </li> tag and there are 4 episodes with a tag of season 4... hence 4,4,4,4

Comment: so it says 'Season 4 Episode 1 Blah blah', 'Season 4 Episode 2 blah blah' 'Season 4 Episode 3 blah blah' and so on?

Comment: Yes that is what it currently outputs, what i want is to put it in a slideshow with tabs listed by the seasons and the episodes in the body. it should look like http://beta.abc.go.com/shows/castle/episode-guide?category=Season+3 but with javascript using jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, given the comments above, I'm guessing you want a structure like this:

```
$old_title = null;
$old_season = null;

foreach ($data as $item) {
    if ($item['title'] != $old_title) {
       echo <<<EOL
<h2><?php echo $item['title'] ?></h2>

EOL;
       $old_title = $item['title'];
    }
    if ($item['season'] != $old_season) {
       echo <<<EOL
<h3>Season <?php echo $item['season'] ?></h3>

EOL;
       $old_season = $item['season'];
    }
    echo <<<EOL
<p>Episode <?php echo $item['number'] ?> | Aired <?php echo $item['airdate'] ?></p>
<p><?php echo $item['plot'] ?></p>

EOL;
}
```

basically, ieep track of which seasons/titles you've output, and only output them when they change. Some extra divs/spans/ids to wrap the various seasons and some css+js to show/hide them and you should be good to go.